# Container fluid only for desktop, lg devices only

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I want to make site with bootstrap 4 grid system. I need to set container-fluid only on desktop sizes and if screen is smaller then lg, to follow the normal container flow.

I tried to set something like this:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { 
    .container {
        width:100%;
        max-width: none;
    }
}
```

but no luck.

Comment: Are you using SASS?

Comment: yes, i do use sass

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `container` to be full (100%) width on lg and up, then pass in the 'lg' breakpoint to the mixin...

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { 
    .container {
        width:100%;
        max-width: none;
    }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/645RLcNcga